# vue.js v-for list not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this list:

```
<ul id="tab">
    <li v-for="list in names">
        {{ list.personName }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then I have this vue object:

```
var vm = new Vue ({
    el: '#tab',
        data: {
            names: //an object array coming from the server
        }
    });
```

So the 'names' data is updated and given information from the server. However, when the names are updated/change, it is not reflected on the client side list. The items that appear in the list only reflect the items that were there when the page initially loaded.

In the vue.js developer tools in Google Chrome, I can always see the updated 'names' data, but it just doesn't reflect on the DOM itself.

**EDIT1**:
What's in the 'name's:

```
names: Array[2]
    0: Object
    _id: "580aeafd017fbfb81a3a794d"
    personName: "hi"

    1: Object
   _id: "580c4455ccc9e39c21f02434"
   personName: "test"
```

**EDIT2**

So I'm using node.js, and transferring the data live from node to the client via socket.io like this:

```
socket.on('userDocument', function(userDocument) {
    var vm= new Vue ({
        el: '#tab',
        data: {
            names: //an object array coming from the server
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using for setting `names` in the component?

Comment: Are you using jQuery for fetching server data? Or do you have `vue-resource` to do that work for you? Can you show that part of code? It helps because there might be a potential issue with binding of `this` in the Promise handlers.

Comment: I'm using nodejs and socket.io to retrieve any changes to the data live, and send it to the client. I know vue.js can see the changes because I checked in the vuejs developers tools in Chrome...it's just the DOM itself that won't update, unless I refresh the page.

Comment: Are you certain the issue is not with socket listeners? Can you read the incoming message via `console.log()` before getting to Vue? You may want to add **socket.io** tag also. Nevertheless, I have written my answer below, check it out.

Comment: Yup, I can read the incoming message via `console.log`. The message is in my EDIT1

Answer (score 37):

Array change detection is a bit tricky in Vue. Most of the in place array methods are working as expected (i.e. doing a splice in your $data.names array would work), but assigining values directly (i.e. $data.names[0] = 'Joe') would not update the reactively rendered components.
Depending on how you process the server side results you might need to think about these options described in the in vue documentation: [Array Change Detection](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection).

Some ideas to explore:

- using the v-bind:key="some_id" to have better
- using the push to add new elements
- using Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue) (also mentioned by Artokun)

Comment: Its weird in my case, i have created a computed property `cUsers` for a data property `users` (array of objects) to check its reactivity. Every time i update that data `users` via fetch, computed property function `cUsers` calls but `v-for loop` for the same data `users` is not updating.

Answer (score 9):

If it's getting passed in as an object from the server, make sure to use Vue.set(obj, key, value) when binding reactively to data().

http://vuejs.org/api/#Vue-set

Comment: To be clear, the data in the array can be all clientside and you'll still need to call `Vue.set` in order to get v-for to re-render based off of the array (as opposed to `arr[idx] = newValue`)

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert on sockets, but that is not the recommended way of handling a socket connection.

A socket sets up a persistent connection with server, and you may get data at any moment from server. Your `socket.on("message", function(data) {...})` is the handler for these asynchronous data from server.

In your sample code, your message handler seems to create a new instance of `Vue()` every time the server sends some data. You will quickly end up with multiple versions of `Vue()` instances, potentially leading to crashing user's browser tab by hogging memory.

I do not use **socket.io**, but based on my understanding of web apps in general, here is how I would prefer to do it:

```js
// Initialize your Vue app first:
new Vue ({
    el: '#tab',
    template: `
        <ul id="tab">
            <li v-for="list in names">
                {{ list.personName }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
    data: {
        names: [] // start with blank, and modify later
    },
    created: function() {
        // This 'created' hook is called when your Vue instance is setup
        // TODO: Initialize your socket connection here.
        // ...
        // Setup your socket listener
        mySocketInstance.on("message", response_data => {
            // Assuming your response_data contains 'user_names' array
            this.names = response_data.user_names;
            // Note: 'this' in the above line points to outer scope, that is why we need arrow functions
        })
    }
});
```

The above code might work for you. You still have to do a lot of testing and debugging. But this is how I would expect things to work.

Note:

1. The code sample creates only one `Vue()` instance, and initializes socket listener in the `created` hook. So there is only one listener / handler for your socket messages.
2. The socket message handler uses javascript arrow function which ensures that your outer scope `this` is same as inner scope `this`. Thus you will be able to update your `names` correctly.

Comment: ahhh, okay. I am going to sort through my code and modify it according to your recommendations. Thank you for all that information.

Comment: Also please check my other comment under the question. You may want to debug the socket side of things also, by using `console.log(server_response)` before getting to Vue.

Answer (score 2):

What I found is even if you pop and then push the element back to the list v-for will not update the list.

For example the code `this.items.pop();` will update the list but the `this.items.push(this.items.pop());` won't. Have no idea why.

As a solution I did the following trick (very ugly, sorry) and it works:

```
<Column v-if="col in columns" ....

methods: {
    refreshColumns() {
        this.columns_temp = [...this.columns];
        this.columns = [];
        this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.columns = [...this.columns_temp];
        });
    },
}
```

I will let you know if I find a proper solution. But at the moment I have no time to do that.

Answer (score 1):

i have a solve.
Use a Component without data.
instead of data , use props for send data to your component
:) it's will work.

Your List:

```
<ul id="tab">
    <my-li v-for="name in names" :my-name="name"></my-li>
</ul>
```

or Your List:

```
<ul id="tab">
    <my-li v-for="name in names">{{name}}</my-li>
</ul>
```

Your Script:

```
let Mycomponent = Vue.component("my-li",{
   props:['my-name'],
   template:"<li>{{myName}}<slot></slot></li>"
});
var vw = new Vue({
  el:"#tab",
  data:{
    names:['ali','reza','matin','mehdi','ahora','me']  
  },
  methods:{
          changeList:function(myList,index,newVal){
              let backupList = this.names;
              backupList[index] = newVal;
              this.names = []
              this.names = backupList;
            }
  },
  component:[Mycomponent]
  })
```

you can change Value of list from this method:

```
vw.changeList(vw.names,1,"hello")
```

if you need set a list to Names Use this

```
vw.names = [];
vw.names = YourList;
```

This Is Easy man :)

result: [jsfiddle.net/khaled_developer/5n316jpo](https://jsfiddle.net/khaled_developer/5n316jpo/)